# Is it possible to use regexes in filtered SLN files?

Tags: visual-studio, sln-file

Giving a simple SLN that contains the following project:

```
├───libs
│   ├───libA
│   │       Class1.cs
│   │       libA.csproj
│   ├───libB
│   │       Class1.cs
│   │       libB.csproj
│   └───libC
│           Class1.cs
│           libC.csproj
└───tools
    ├───toolA
    │       Program.cs
    │       toolA.csproj
    └───toolB
            Program.cs
            toolB.csproj
```

I would like to have an [filtered SLN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2019) that only loads the projects under `libs` folder without having to list all the projects one by one.

I tried to create an `.slnf` with the following content:

```json
{
  "solution": {
    "path": "Solution.sln",
    "projects": [
      "libs\\**\\*.csproj",
    ]
  }
}
```

When loading the `slnf` in Visual Studio 2019, none of the project are loaded when I was expecting to have see the projects under the `libs` folder.

I also tried a couple of other formats such as `libs\\.*\\.*.csproj`, but none of them seems to work.

Does filtered SLN supports regexes in the list of projects? If yes, how to use it?

Comment: `libs` and `tools` folders are located directly inside folder where `.sln` file is located? Did this work with specific paths instead of regex?

Comment: There's an open request to add this, so I assume it doesn't currently exist: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/solution-filter-should-allow-for-includeexclude-ba/1090914

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, when I list the projects one by one, yes it works.

Comment: @devNull, you must be right, the feature does not exist yet. Upvoting it!